I have a Shimano deore m5100 cassette and have found it doesn’t fit on the freehub body that is on my bike just wondering what freehub body i need
Shimano Deore 11 speed cassette
7 speed cassette to 9 speed cassette
Have removed original 7 speed cassette and tried to fit new 11 speed and the free gun isn’t long enough for all the gears on the 11 speed cassette wondering what freehub body I need?

Your question is a bit confusing as currently stated. If the question as I understand it is why doesn't my 7-speed (or is it 9-speed) compatible freehub allow an 11-speed freehub to fit, the answer is first: it it not compatible with most 11 speed freehubs (some Shimano MTB cassettes may fit), and second: there are so many different wheels and freehubs out there, we do not have a hope of answering the "what freehub do I need? question.  That said, there are not many wheels where the freehub can be swapped to be 11-speed compatible.

A 7 speed cassette is just one generation too old to be useful.   8 through 10 speed all shared the same outer width by making the gears closer together, but 7 speed cassettes are narrower, so the freehub is shorter and won't take a 8/9/10 speed cassette.
If you can find an 11 speed freehub that fits your wheel's hub, then that would allow use of an 11 speed cassette.
Or you might find an 8/9/10/11 speed wheel and swap the whole thing into your bike.
If the resulting wheel is too wide for your frame, then it goes from fairly expensive to really-expensive.  A steel frame can be slightly widened, but an aluminium one or carbon frame cannot be widened at all.
Also you need a new 11 speed derailleur and shifter, and you may as well fit a new inner and outer cable at the same time.
